# What is adiabatic transfer?

Tags: atomic-physics, terminology, quantum-states, adiabatic, laser-interaction

In the context of atomic/quantum states preparation, what does adiabatic transfer mean? I'm currently reading about atom preparation using lasers and they talk about using adiabatic transfer to obtain a coherent population inversion. I´m failing to understand what does exactly "adiabatic transfer" mean and how/why to use a laser to obtain it. This is not my area nor language and this is my first question so I hope it´s okay.

Comment: The key word is likely [STIRAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimulated_Raman_adiabatic_passage), standing for stimulated raman adiabatic passage.